# Pick the all checked items from the component - Multi select Check box

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have **multi-select checkbox** list as shown below. Can you tell me how to pick the all checked items from the component (`.ts`)?

**.html:**

```html
<ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let i of inputs">
          <ion-label>{{i.display}}</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox name="{{i.label}}" [(ngModel)]="i.checked"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**.ts:**

```js
this.inputs=[
        {
            "encode": "1",
            "display": "en falls asleep without a caregiver in the room",
            "label": "uiFallsAsleepUnassistedBedTime",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "encode": "2",
            "display": "During breastfeeding",
            "label": "uiBreastFeedBedTime",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "encode": "3",
            "display": "Being rocked or held (in arms or baby sling/carrier)",
            "label": "uiSlingBedTime",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "encode": "4",
            "display": "In motion (stroller, car, etc.)",
            "label": "uiInMotionBedTime",
            "checked": false
        },

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP's Feedback:** Below one is working for me.

```
this.inputs.filter(opt => opt.checked).map(opt => opt.label);
```

**Original Answer:**

I think you should bind `i.checked` instead of `i. encode` to `ion-checkbox`. and then you can use `Array.filter` to get the checked items.

```
var inputs = [{
    "encode": "1",
    "display": "en falls asleep without a caregiver in the room",
    "label": "uiFallsAsleepUnassistedBedTime",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "encode": "2",
    "display": "During breastfeeding",
    "label": "uiBreastFeedBedTime",
    "checked": true
  },
  {
    "encode": "3",
    "display": "Being rocked or held (in arms or baby sling/carrier)",
    "label": "uiSlingBedTime",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "encode": "4",
    "display": "In motion (stroller, car, etc.)",
    "label": "uiInMotionBedTime",
    "checked": true
  },
]

console.log(inputs.filter(function(item){ return item.checked === true; }));
```

Comment: Nope.I need to get the `checked` values of the `multi-select checkbox` list.It is a dynamic list and user can change the values.

Comment: @Sampath Did you try this solution? I think this should work just change your `ngModel` to `i.checked`. If user change any `checkbox` then `checked` value for that inputs should update and Array.filter give you the desire result.

Comment: @Sampath If you bind `i.encode` to `ngModel`, when user changed the status of the checkbox, the value of `encode` will be changed to 0 or 1, is this what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model item state checked variable then you can add a binding to the attribute

```html
<ion-checkbox name="{{i.label}}" [(ngModel)]="i.encode" [checked]="i.checked" (change)="change(i, $event)"></ion-checkbox>
```

**.ts code:**

```ts
  checked = [];

  change(item, event) {
    var index = this.inputs.map(i => i.encode).indexOf(item.encode);
    if(event.target.checked) {
      if(index === -1) {
        this.checked.push(item);
      }
    } else {
      if(index !== -1) {
        this.checked.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you show the `.ts` code also? How can I pick the `checked` items only from the component (`.ts`)?

Comment: And we cannot use this`[value]="i.encode"`. It is not an `Ionic check box` property.

Comment: you pick all and those that have `checked=true` will be checked

Comment: My problem is how to do that? Can you show the TS code for that?